# Is there any way to know version requiements between Subversion and Maven?

Tags: java, maven, svn

Is there any way to know version requiements between Subversion and Maven? For example, is it possible to use Subversion 1.6.12 with Maven 3?

I guess version of SVN may be importamnt for [Maven SCM Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/) and [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/). But I have not fouund any documentation related to this.

Comment: Subversion 1.6 is several dot releases behind current production 1.10.  What have you tried?

Comment: @duffymo actually I have not tried. There is old project what use SVN 1.6 client and Maven 2. I want to know will it be requierd to use newer version of SVN if project will be migrated to Maven 3. But the main question is "Is there any way to know version requiements between Subversion and Maven? " to be able to check compatability next time if will be requierd.

Comment: The best advice is to try it.  You should be using Maven 3 and a newer SVN.  Try it with Maven 3 and see if you need to upgrade after that.

Comment: @duffymo the problem is I do not have access to that project now. I think I need create some test project and check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it matters as the SCM Plugin is a wrapper that will choose the suitable SCM provider implementation to execute SCM commands according to the SCM configured in your pom.xml (and maybe some checks before the execution of the SCM goals).

You can read in the documentation page you quote :

> The SCM Plugin offers vendor independent access to common scm commands
>   by offering a set of command mappings for the configured scm. Each
>   command is implemented as a goal.

I would add that the documentation doesn't refer such compatibility issues or requirement to set a specific version of the SCM plugin.
And I personally never noticed such an issue with the SCM plugin.
But I cannot affirm that it will be fine in all cases (while it should in at least the most of them), so I advise to make some tests to ensure that all is working between the targeted Maven version and the targeted SCM version.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thank you.